# XSLT 2.0 - Date difference between a historic date and today in number of years,months,days (YYMMDD format)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I spent almost half a day to figure this out but could not achieve it. Can someone help me out, please?

I am looking to get a date difference between a historic date and today in terms of number of years, months and days in YYMMDD format.

For example, if a historic date is in format 2017-06-01-07:00, then the expected value is 000016 as that's the date difference between historic date and today.

Similarly, if historic date is 2016-07-27-07:00, then the expected value is 001019, which means date difference is 0 years, 10 months, 19 days since the historic date.

Comment: Just to make sure, what is the `-07:00` part in your input format, a timezone offset?

Comment: That is hh:mm, yes that's a timezone offset from the UTC time

Comment: You can construct an `xs:date` directly from your input format with e.g. `xs:date('2017-06-01-07:00')`, you can also substract `current-date() div xs:date('2017-06-01-07:00')` to get a duration, however that is in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be aware that expressing a date difference in years, months and days is pretty much meaningless.

Years and months do not have a constant length in days and consequently two calculations measuring durations that are equal in terms of elapsed days may easily return different results in terms of years, months and days.

For the same reason, there is no established algorithm for calculating a date difference in years, months and days.

All that said, if you wish to *display* the elapsed period in years, months and days - as an illustration, for example - you can use the following method:

```
<xsl:template name="date-diff-in-ymd">
    <xsl:param name="start-date"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="start-year" select="year-from-date($start-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start-month" select="month-from-date($start-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start-day" select="day-from-date($start-date)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="end-year" select="year-from-date($end-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="end-month" select="month-from-date($end-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="end-day" select="day-from-date($end-date)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="elapsed-months" select="12*($end-year - $start-year) + $end-month - $start-month - number($end-day lt $start-day)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="birthday" select="$start-date + xs:yearMonthDuration(concat('P0Y', $elapsed-months, 'M'))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="years" select="$elapsed-months idiv 12"/>
    <xsl:variable name="months" select="$elapsed-months mod 12"/>
    <xsl:variable name="days" select="days-from-duration($end-date - $birthday)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($years, ' years, ', $months, ' months and ', $days, ' days')" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

Example of call: http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwM

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference between two dates $d1 and $d2 as an xs:dayTimeDuration using the expression `$d2 - $d1`. The result is in days (you can convert it to an integer number of days by dividing by `xs:yearMonthDuration('PT1D')`. Translating this to years, months, and days directly probably isn't going to give satisfactory results: what answer do you want for the difference between 2016-02-29 and 2017-02-28? If you know of an algorithm that works, then expressing it in XSLT shouldn't be too difficult, but you'll have to explain the algorithm if you want help with the coding.