# XSLT: Year difference between two dates

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I would like to compute the year difference between two dates in XSLT 2.0. I tried:

```
xs:dayTimeDuration(xs:date('2007-03-02')-xs:date('2002-03-01'))
```

giving me the difference in days:

```
P1827D
```

What would help would be a function that calculates a somehow "normalized" `xs:duration` in years, months *and* days between two dates, like `P1Y0M1D` in this example, which I can extract the year `P1Y` from. Extracting a year from an `xs:duration` consisting of days only, as above, is not possible (and wouldn't make much sense either).

So how do I compute the difference of two dates in years, not in days?

Comment: Not sure what exactly "*year difference between wo dates*" means. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585270/3016153

Comment: Something like `diff('2002-03-03', '2007-03-02')` returning a duration of `'P4Y'` (4 years).

Comment: That's not a clear example. What is the difference between 2003-03-01 and 2004-02-29? Give us a rule, not an example.

Comment: The rule is to return the difference of two dates in years, rounded to the floor.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-years-from-duration

Comment: @Siebe Jongebloed: will always return 0 when you have an xs:duration measured in days only.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic I am afraid that makes no sense to me whatsoever. Floor has meaning only when the input is a non-integer number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to return a result that is equivalent to *age* expressed in whole years, using the customary rule where the age increases by one on each birthday. This could be calculated using the following template (which you could turn into a function):

```
<xsl:template name="age-in-years">
    <xsl:param name="start-date"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-date"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="start-year" select="year-from-date($start-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start-month" select="month-from-date($start-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start-day" select="day-from-date($start-date)"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="end-year" select="year-from-date($end-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="end-month" select="month-from-date($end-date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="end-day" select="day-from-date($end-date)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$end-year - $start-year - number(100 * $end-month + $end-day lt 100 * $start-month + $start-day)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Do note that this assumes the birthday of a person born on February 29 occurs on March 1 in a non-leap year.

Comment: But the OP also asked for the difference in years, months, and days, which is rather more difficult to define.

Comment: @MichaelKay The above is actually a simplification of a solution that returns the difference in years, months, and days - a solution at which I pointed the OP in my first comment to their question. If you read more carefully, you will see that they asked for this only so that they can extract the year component from it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a recursive solution by myself. It is not the most performant, but it works:

```
<xsl:function name="d:years-diff">
    <xsl:param name="old.date" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:param name="new.date" as="xs:date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="one-year" select="xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y')"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$old.date + $one-year &lt;= $new.date">
            <xsl:sequence select="$one-year + d:years-diff($old.date + $one-year, $new.date)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="xs:yearMonthDuration('P0Y')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

You can verify the function using the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;One day short of five years:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2002-03-02'), xs:date('2007-03-01'))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;Exactly 5 years:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2002-03-02'), xs:date('2007-03-02'))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;One day short of one year:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2007-03-02'), xs:date('2006-03-01'))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;Exactly one year:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2006-03-02'), xs:date('2007-03-02'))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;One year plus one day:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2006-03-02'), xs:date('2007-03-03'))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;Same dates:&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="d:years-diff(xs:date('2007-03-03'), xs:date('2007-03-03'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which prints out:

```
One day short of five years:
P4Y
Exactly 5 years:
P5Y
One day short of one year:
P0M
Exactly one year:
P1Y
One year plus one day:
P1Y
Same dates:
P0M
```